# Google Analytics: No HTTP Response Detected

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to track my webpage using Google Analytics on GoDaddy.  I have never run into an issue using it before; however, Google Tag Manager is telling me that there was no HTTP Response Detected from the Google Analytics Tag.

> Missing HTTP Response denotes that, while the Google Analytics code
>   was detected in the page source, the script itself did not execute.
>   Each time the Google Analytics script executes, we expect an HTTP
>   Response carrying the tracking request to Google’s servers. This means
>   that the Google Analytics code is not implemented properly on the page
>   and no data will be collected.
>   https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154#http_response

Does anything stick out to anyone in the head of this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Page Information -->
    <meta name="description" content="...">
    <meta name="author" content="...">
    <title>Happening</title>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icons/favicon-194x194.png" sizes="194x194">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="img/icons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#571619">
    <!-- Shows error when validated, but is legal -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Happening">
    <meta name="application-name" content="Happening">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/icons/mstile-144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="img/icons/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#571619">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- JS Libs  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-77358803-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: link to your website is correct in settings Google Analytics ?

Comment: @SkiesX Yes, I believe so.  When I click "Sent Test Traffic", it directs itself to the proper URL.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be in the body and not the head? that's what I read....

Answer (score 4):

Try using the debug version of analytics.  Change the analytics URL to https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js (per the advice [from Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging)).  It will display information and warnings in the console.  In my case, it gave me a warning that 'ga' was already defined (another script I was including had polluted the global name space).

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you viewing the site while logged in to WordPress when you get this warning?
2. In the Analytics settings (Site Kit > Settings > Analytics > Edit), do you have the option to exclude logged-in users from tracking enabled?
3. If so, when you disable this option does the warning in Tag Assistant go away?

If that is the case, that warning is normal and indicates that option to prevent the tracking of logged-in users is working. You can choose to keep this option on or off depending on what you would like track in Analytics.